# Unable to set scope games::prime for Login with Amazon

Tags: asp.net-core, login-with-amazon

I've been tryin to setup an external login with amazon to integrate prime gaming for my web app in asp net core 3.1. I've been following this [Amazon Prime Gaming Integration](https://developer.amazon.com/es-mx/docs/primegaming/integrations/push-manage-accounts.html). I have been successfully stored the amazon userId, its token, refresh token and expires in into my database. However, I'm unable to call a post API request to **/api/account/link** to sync up my account according to this document. I am getting an error with message: **Not all permissions are authorized**. I did a bit research and it mentioned in another document link ([Tips-Troubleshoot](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/primegaming/integrations/tips-troubleshooting.html)) that I need to set both scopes to **games::prime** and **profile** (I only had profile set before).

However, when adding **games::prime** scope, I get an exception for invalid scope:  **invalid_scope;Description=An unknown scope was requested**

I'm using **AspNet.Security.OAuth.Amazon** to help with the external login with amazon, and this is the code that I have in my **Startup.cs** file

```
services.AddAuthentication()                     
                .AddAmazon(o =>
                {
                    o.ClientId = clientId;
                    o.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                    o.Scope.Add("profile");
                    o.Scope.Add("games::prime");
                    o.SaveTokens = true; // get access token and refresh token
                    o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/WebAppSetting");
                })
```

If I remove **games::prime** from the scope, then everything works but then I will get an error message **Not all permissions are authorized**

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing and not doing correct in here ? I have been searching for amazon documents on their sites, but seems like there is nothing useful there.

Thank you

Comment: Does anyone not have an answer for this question ? I feel so dumb rn...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that in order to use scope games::prime, you need to contact amazon team to have them unblock that for you. This is not mentioned at all in the push integration documentation.